# How to fix wrong variables "go env GOROOT"?

Tags: go, terminal, gopath

I made a mistake:

`go env -w GOROOT=/Users/apple/Documents/testProject/GXB_be:/usr/local/go`

I set a wrong path as a variable of go env.
This makes it almost impossible for me to use the go env command in the vscode terminal,so I cannot directly use this command to repair it.

```
% go env
go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /Users/apple/Documents/testProject/GXB_be:/usr/local/go
```

I refer to this document https://go.dev/doc/install , tried to reinstall go, and tried to restart the vscode terminal, or even the macbook, but it did not work.

I think this is a global problem, because it not only affects vscode, but also occurs on the terminal.

My environment：
go version go1.19.3 darwin/amd64
vscode 1.72.2 (Universal)

Now I have temporarily solved this problem by importing environment variables.
However, every time a new vscode terminal is created, the problem still exists.

```
% go env
go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /Users/apple/Documents/testProject/GXB_be:/usr/local/go
% export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
% go env
warning: GOPATH set to GOROOT (/usr/local/go) has no effect
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
...
```

How can I restore the environment?

Comment: Does running `GOROOT= go env -w GOROOT=/usr/local/go` fix the problem?

Comment: Or may be `GOROOT=/usr/local/go go env -w GOROOT=/usr/local/go`

Comment: Remove (or edit) /Users/<you>/Library/Application Support/go/env.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestions can solve this problem. @Volker

Answer (score 1):

Remove (or edit) /Users//Library/Application Support/go/env.
-- from Volker